# How to close Activity after show over lock screen?

Tags: android, lockscreen

I'm developing an alarm clock app.
When the alarm goes off I want the User can pause the alarm over the lock screen. When the alarm is paused the User will not perform any more activity in the app. Thus, when the User unlock the phone my application must be closed.

I used the flag (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED) on onAttachedToWindow() to display the activity frame above the lock screen, however so far not found a way to keep the application closed when the User unlocks the lock screen